CSS Display Counter Value in Minutes
I am working on a countdown in css to display time left for certain metrics.  Everything is working well, with the exception that I can only display the remaining time in seconds, instead of minutes.
From my understanding of countdown animations, they only accept time in seconds or milliseconds.  My timer is for 25 minutes so I have it set for 1500 seconds and it works great.  I cannot find a way to divide the results of my counter s by 60 to get the time to display in minutes using countdown content.  I have also tired just basic calc(1 + 1) and trying to get that result to display in content, but have be unsuccessful.  It would seem that any calculated result will down display in content.  It felt like a variable type issue, but don't believe CSS uses typed variables.
I have been trying to avoid adding JavaScript into this project, but would that be the recommendation to move forward or is there something I am missing with the CSS?


    @property --t {
      syntax: "<number>";
      initial-value: 1500;      
      inherits: true;
    }
    
    /* won't be needed once Chrome supports round() */
    @property --s {
      syntax: "<integer>";
      initial-value: 0;
      inherits: true;
    }
    
    .countdown {
      --s: calc(var(--t)/1);
      display: grid;
      margin: 1em auto;
      width: 20em;      
      height: 20em;     
      animation: t 1500s linear forwards ;    
    }
    
    .countdown::after {
      grid-column: 1;
      grid-row: 1;
      place-self: center;
      font: 5em/2 ubuntu mono, consolas, monaco, monospace; 
      counter-reset: s var(--s);     
      --k: counter(s);
      content: var(--k);            
    }
    <body>
    <div style="font: 5em/2 ubuntu mono, consolas, monaco, monospace;color:black;text-align: center;">Processing</div>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <div class="countdown">
      <svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" stroke-width="10">
        <circle r="45"></circle>
        <circle r="45" pathLength="1"></circle>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <!-- partial -->
      
    </body>



I started with this code and adapted to my needs.  In this example the leading 0: appears to just be a string prefix for aesthetics.
https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/RwPNaEd

Pls provide your HTML as well.

Updated to include HTML

Could you make a runnable snippet so we can see the animation and counter changing.

It was adopted from: https://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/RwPNaEd and you can see it in action.

So basically you want that same effect but the text displaying minutes only instead of minutes + seconds?

@DanielCruz That's correct.  As-is it never displayed minutes, just seconds.  It was the example came hard coded with "0:" as padding to the seconds.  After struggling for hours I would take either total minutes or hours : minutes.  I figured total minutes would be easier and just as effective.

This has all of the above. HH:MM:SS.

Your snippet is missing the important bit which is updating the counter and displaying it. Please include that code so we can see it running. It’s no good asking us to look at an external site which may disappear at some point so rendering the question useless for future readers.

You could have a minute counter, which is (--t - 60)/60

It's overall simple.
Doing the calculation
You need to calculate the minutes based on the seconds you got. The simple formula is --m: round(var(--s) / 60); where m is minutes and s is seconds. Because round is not globally available (yet), you have to use some tricks to emulate it. So the final formula would be something like this: --m: max(0, var(--t)/60 - 0.5); (the full explanation for the formula is here, gut in short the - 0.5 is used to round down, the max is used to prevent negatives when the number is below 1 and --m is defined as integer to round the value)
If you want also to show the seconds the process is similar. The formula would be s = t - m * 60 which translated to css with the limitations we have would be --s: calc(var(--t) - var(--m)*60 - 0.5);
Displaying both values
finally you just have to define both minutes and seconds on your counter to display them like so: counter-reset: s var(--s) m var(--m);
and then, instead of the '00:' which was burned in, we display the minutes like so: content: counter(m) ':' counter(s, decimal-leading-zero);
if you only want to show the minutes, you can delete the seconds part like so: content: counter(m); (and remove the calculation as well)
Fully working example
and that's it, this is a fully working example, based on the pen you provided (this is how it would look like with about 90 seconds set up)
https://codepen.io/danicruz0415/pen/pomvzXe

Full code reference
here is the full code in case the pen stops working. I dont put it like a runnable snipped because its done in scss and pug but you can adapt it later to your code, because the code you provided was not fully working
- let d = 100, o = -.5*d;
- let sw = .1*d, r = .5*(d - sw);

.countdown
    svg(viewBox=[o, o, d, d].join(' ') stroke-width=sw)
        circle(r=r)
        circle(r=r pathLength='1')

$d: 20em;
$t: 90;
$c: #8a9b0f #940a3d;

@property --t {
    syntax: '<number>';
    initial-value: #{$t};
    inherits: true
}

@property --m {
  syntax: '<integer>';
  initial-value: 0;
  inherits: true;
}

/* won't be needed once Chrome supports round() */
@property --s {
    syntax: '<integer>';
    initial-value: 0;
    inherits: true
}

.countdown {
    /* when Chrome supports round(), this can be simplified */
    /* more on this rounding trick
     * https://css-tricks.com/using-absolute-value-sign-rounding-and-modulo-in-css-today/ */
    --m: max(0, var(--t)/60 - 0.5);
  --s: calc(var(--t) - var(--m)*60 - 0.5);
    display: grid;
    margin: 1em auto;
    width: $d; height: $d;
    animation: t $t*1s linear infinite;
    
    &::after {
        grid-column: 1;
        grid-row: 1;
        place-self: center;
        font: #{.25*$d}/ 2 ubuntu mono, consolas, monaco, monospace;
        counter-reset: s var(--s) m var(--m);
        content: counter(m) ':' counter(s, decimal-leading-zero) 
    }
}

@keyframes t { to { --t: 0 } }

svg {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1
}

[r] {
    fill: none;
    stroke: silver;
    
    + [r] {
        --k: calc(var(--t)/#{$t});
        transform: rotate(-90deg);
        stroke-linecap: round;
        stroke: color-mix(in hsl shorter hue, #{nth($c, 1)} calc(var(--k)*100%), #{nth($c, 2)});
        stroke-dasharray: var(--k) 1
    }
}


It's worth noting, this kind of interactivity is where js would ideally come into play. Accomplishing this without some kind of css preprocessor would be bulky and redundant. I do love your answer though.

This is amazing.  Thank you for your time and effort into explaining how your created the solution.

I thought you might enjoy seeing how this could be accomplished with js instead of pure css solution.


const wait = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

const countdownEl = document.querySelector(".countdown-wrap");

const setDeg = deg => {
  countdownEl.style.setProperty(
    "--deg",
    deg + "deg"
  );
};

const setColor = color => {
  countdownEl.style.setProperty(
    "--color",
    color
  );
};

const setPercent = percent => {
  const deg = 360 * percent / 100;
  setDeg(deg.toFixed(2));
  const green = 255 * percent / 100;
  const red = 255 * (1 - percent / 100);
  const rgb = `rgb(${red}, ${green}, 0)`;
  setColor(rgb);
};

const disableButtons = () => {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.disabled = true;
  });
};

const enableButtons = () => {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
  buttons.forEach(button => {
    button.disabled = false;
  });
};

const time = document.querySelector(".time-display");

const countdown = async s => {
  disableButtons();
  let max = Number(s);
  let current = -1;
  while (current !== max) {
    current++;
    const remaining = max - current;
    setPercent(remaining / max * 100);
    time.innerText = remaining + "s";
    await wait(1000);
  }
  enableButtons();
};

const thirtyButton = document.querySelector("button.thirty");

const fifteenButton = document.querySelector("button.fifteen");

thirtyButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  countdown(30);
});

fifteenButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  countdown(15);
});

const customButton = document.querySelector("button.custom");
const timeInput = document.querySelector("input");

customButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
  countdown(timeInput.value);
});
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: grid; 
  place-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  height: 100dvh;
}

input {
  width: 5ch;
}

@property --deg {
  syntax: '<angle>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0deg;
}

@property --color {
  syntax: '<color>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: green;
}

.countdown-wrap {
  --size: 150px;
  --deg: 0deg;
  --color: rgb(0, 200, 0);
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: conic-gradient(
    var(--color) var(--deg), lightgrey var(--deg)
  );
  transition: --deg .2s linear, --color .2s linear;
}

.countdown-wrap {
  display: grid; 
  place-items: center;
}

.time-display {
  background: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius:50%;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}
<div class="countdown-wrap">
  <div class="time-display">0s</div>
</div>
<div class="button-wrap">
  <button class="fifteen">15s</button>
  <button class="thirty">30s</button> <br>
  <input min="1" value="5" type="number">       
  <button class="custom">start</button>
</div>



